# How can I keep only non-zero digits from an integer?

Tags: c++

I am currently using the code below that removes all digits equal to zero from an integer.

```
int removeZeros(int candid)
{
     int output = 0;
     string s(itoa(candid));
     for (int i = s.size(); i != 0; --i)
     {
         if (s[i] != '0') output = output * 10 + atoi(s[i]);
     }
     return output;
}
```

The expected output for e.g. 102304 would be 1234.

Is there a more compact way of doing this by directly ***working on the integer***, that is, ***not string representation***? Is it actually going to be faster?

Comment: You have your parameter as type `int`, but you don't appear to be handling negative numbers at all. Also, it's not clear from your requirements what the result of `removeZeros(0)` should be.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: with pure math it should be definitely faster...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ using pure math and avoiding the string conversion would most likely be faster, and be more efficient space complexity wise too

Comment: How should '0' input be handled?

Comment: @g24l that is not a case. A check 0 before calling the method, would do. Same goes for negative numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
template<typename T> T nozeros( T const & z )
{
  return z==0 ? 0 : (z%10?10:1)*nozeros(z/10)+(z%10);
}
```

If you want to take your processing one step further you can do a nice tail recursion , no need for a helper function:

```
template<typename T> inline T pow10(T p, T res=1)
{
  return p==0 ? res : pow10(--p,res*10);
}

template<typename T> T nozeros( T const & z , T const & r=0, T const & zp =0)
{
  static int digit =-1;
  return not ( z ^ r ) ? digit=-1, zp : nozeros(z/10,z%10, r ? r*pow10(++digit)+zp : zp);
}
```

Here is how this will work with input 32040

Ret, z, r, zp, digits

-,32040,0,0,  -1

-,3204,0,0,    -1

-,320,4,0,0,    -1

-,32,0,4,4,      0

-,3,2,4,            0

-,0,3,24,          1

-,0,0,324,        2

324,-,-,-,         -1

Integer calculations are always faster than actually transforming your integer to string, making comparisons on strings, and looking up strings to turn them back to integers.

The cool thing is that if you try to pass floats you get nice compile time errors.

I claim this to be slightly faster than other solutions as it makes less conditional evaluations which will make it behave better with CPU branch prediction.

Comment: `std::cout << nozeros(10203) << std::endl;` prints `60`. You may be able to modify your code to make it work, but a code-only answer with zero explanation, where the code doesn't actually work, doesn't help anybody.

Comment: @hvd thanks for pointing this out , I will look into it, and repost ASAP.

Comment: Nice job on editing it to a form that looks like it works, but: "since is a tail recursion" -- no, it's not. Tail recursion is when you return the result of some other invocation of `nozeros` directly. That's not what you're doing. The fact that your call appears inside the `return` expression doesn't automatically make it tail recursion.

Comment: @hvd, actually true, that it is not a tail call. the second evaluation has a second conditional. I am sure I can transform it as such, but can't do it right now( have to catch a plane...), I will rephrase and see later.

Comment: Making it tail recursive involves an `nonzeros_(int n, int m, int a)` helper function, which returns the same value as `nonzeros(n) * m + a` would. You can then implement `nonzeros(n)` as `nonzeros_(n, 1, 0)`, and implement `nonzeros_(n, m, a)` as returning `n == 0 ? 0 : nonzeros_(n / 10, (z%10?10:1)*m, m*a+z%10)`. (Beware: I may have silly errors in there.) It's not the fact that it appears in a conditional expression that's itself a problem, it's the multiplication and addition you do to the result of it.

Comment: @hvd hey man that's what I am talking about, do you want to edit th answer!? I just don't have time to do now. But I think it's the proper way to improve this. Thanks

Comment: I warned about silly errors in my comment, and already spotted two after re-reading. I can't take responsibility for any version that gets included in your answer. :) But don't worry, if you don't have time to edit right now, there's no problem at all editing your answer later.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way to do it without strings and buffers.

I've only tested this with positive numbers. To make this work with negative numbers is an exercise left up to you.

```
int removeZeros(int x)
{
    int result = 0;
    int multiplier = 1;
    while (x > 0)
    {
        int digit = x % 10;
        if (digit != 0)
        {
            int val = digit * multiplier;
            result += val;
            multiplier *= 10;
        }
        x = x / 10;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For maintainability, I would suggest, *don't* work directly on the numeric value. You can express your requirements in a very straightforward way using string manipulations, and while it's true that it will likely perform slower than number manipulations, I expect either to be fast enough that you don't have to worry about the performance unless it's in an extremely tight loop.

```
int removeZeros(int n) {
  auto s = std::to_string(n);
  s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), '0'), s.end());
  return std::stoi(s);
}
```

As a bonus, this simpler implementation handles negative numbers correctly. For zero, it throws `std::invalid_argument`, because removing all zeros from `0` doesn't produce a number.

Comment: Your answer is much better than mine. Nice!

Comment: Why the down-vote?
hvd: I think building up the string and then removing the zeroes from it is (probably considerably) slower than just creating a string without zeroes.

Comment: @black If the removing of zeros involves reallocations, I would agree with you, but are there reallocations here? This is supposed to just modify the data in-place.

Comment: It's not for the reallocation (no, there shouldn't be any) but for the `remove` operation itself, because it has to `swap` every `'0'` to the end. You could just do that while creating the string (so you avoid `to_string`).

Comment: @black Ah, right, but that's an O(n) operation where n is guaranteed to be extremely small, it's limited to the maximum number of digits that can appear in the string representation of an integer. The time for that should be insignificant; you would need to call the function *extremely* often in order for the saved time to outweigh the extra time needed to implement `std::to_string` manually, as simple as that may be. If that should become significant, I'd rather avoid `std::string` altogether.

Comment: Interesting, but you are doing a string transform. Not what I asked for. Maintenance is not an issue, performance is.

Comment: @janejoj Let me then answer exactly one question you asked: "Is it actually going to be faster?" My answer to that is "Maybe, but not enough to worry about it."

Comment: True mister, but we are in a situation that we have to worry about it. Thought thunbs up for using stl to do this. Really I like your suggestion, it's just doesn't answer within the context of the question. Many thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

No string representation is used here. I can't say anything about the speed though.

```
int removezeroes(int candid)
{
    int x, y = 0, n = 0;

    // I did this to reverse the number as my next loop 
    // reverses the number while removing zeroes.
    while (candid>0)
    {
        x = candid%10;
        n = n *10 + x;
        candid /=10;
    }
    candid = n;
    while (candid>0)
    {
        x = candid%10;
        if (x != 0)
            y = y*10 + x;
        candid /=10;
    }
    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) is available, I do like this with lambda function:

```
int removeZeros(int candid){
    std::string s=std::to_string(candid);
    std::string output;
    std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), [&](char& c){ if (c != '0') output += c;});
    return std::stoi(output);
}
```

Comment: Tip: use `std::remove` for simplicity (like I did in my answer) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int number = 9042100;
stringstream strm;
strm << number;
string str = strm.str();
str.erase(remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '0'), str.end());
number = atoi(str.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

A fixed implementation of g24l recursive solution:

```
template<typename T> T nozeros(T const & z)
{   
  if (z == 0) return 0;
  if (z % 10 == 0) return nozeros(z / 10);
  else return (z % 10) + ( nozeros(z / 10) * 10);
}
```

Comment: I think you should make this function non-template, because OP uses usual function.